# Abrir PopUp por cima de outro PopUp

Tags: javascript, popup

Da para abrir um popup por cima de outro popup?
tenho um janela que é aberta em um popup, para se cadastrar cliente, nessa janela eu preciso abrir um outro popup, para cadastrar ou puxar umas informações adicionais. mas sempre que eu clico no botão, ele não abre o popup e sim manda o popup que está aberto, para o endereço do popup que era pra abrir

Não coloco o HTML, pq é muita coisa tag. mas vou colocar os dois scripts que eu to usando e os links que eu uso

Link que abre o popup de cadastro de cliente

```
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:newPopup()">Clientes</a></li>
```

Script do cadastro do cliente:

```
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
    function newPopup() {
        var width = screen.width;
        var height = screen.height;
        varWindow = window.open('/Gerencial/ClienteGerencial/Cliente', 'popup', "width=1353, height=646, scrollbars=no,type=fullWindow,fullscreen,scrollbars=yes, menubar=no ");
    }
</script>
```

Botão que teóricamente era pra abrir o outro popup por cima do popUp do cadastro do cliente:

```
 <button class="btn botoes" onclick="parceiroEContador();">
                                            <img src="~/Content/iconBtn/contador_16x16.png" />
                                            Contador
                                        </button>
```

Script que era para abrir:

```
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
    function parceiroEContador() {
        //var width = screen.width;
        //var height = screen.height;
        varWindow = window.open('/Gerencial/ClienteGerencial/ParceiroEContador', 'popup', "width=600, height=600, scrollbars=no,type=fullWindow,fullscreen,scrollbars=yes, menubar=no ");
    }
</script>
```

Ou seja, eu consigo abrir o primeiro popup de cadastro de cliente normalmente, mas quando eu tento abrir um novo pop por cima desse popup não consigo, apenas redireciona o popup atual para o endereço `/Gerencial/ClienteGerencial/ParceiroEContador`

Comment: Indico você usar modal tem o IziModal que é fácil de usar até demais.

Comment: boa dica, estou lendo a documentação dele, é muito bom msm, inclusive, é uma opção melhor do que abrir um popup por cima de outro. Obrigado, eu não conhecia

Comment: Se quiser coloco um exemplo com ele bem pratico

Comment: opa, quero sim... ele não é complicado, mas algumas funções me deixam com duvidas.. rsrsr obrigado

Comment: Fiz uma resposta vê se entendeu.

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modais com izi modal exemplo prático

Dentro do body:

```
<button class="abrirModal">Abrir modal</butto>
<div id="modal" class="fade">
//Conteúdo do modal
<button class="outroModal">Abrir outro modal</button>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.abrirModal').on('click', '.abrirModal', function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         $('#modal').removeClass('fade');
         $('#modal').iziModal('open');
});
$('#modal').iziModal({
    'title': 'Modal de texte',
    'transitionIn': 'fadeDown',
    'transitionOut: 'fadeOutUp'
});
$(document).on('click', '.outroModal', function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#outroModal').removeClass('fade');
       $('#outroModal').iziModal('open');
});
$('#outroModal').iziModal({
    'title': 'Outro modal de texte',
    'transitionIn': 'fadeDown',
    'transitionOut: 'fadeOutUp'
});
});
```

a class "Fade" é do bootstrap mas pode tentar usar sem ela para vê se ele não fica aparecendo espero ter te ajudado até aqui.